# ubuntu 9.04 /var/www permissions

Tags: ubuntu, unix, permissions, apache-http-server, webserver

ubuntu 9.04, user luca wants to access the /var/www directory.

the directory is owned by user root, group root

I changed the group ownership to www-data (sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/) and added write privileges to that group (sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www), and added luca to that group (sudo adduser luca www-data).

Now, why can't luca still write to /var/www?
It should be able to, right?

in /etc/group we have: "www-data:x:33:luca"

permissions for /var/www are: "drwxrwxr-x  2 root www-data 4096 Feb 26 15:35 www"

Comment: Works for me. Maybe luca has to relogin?

Comment: Yes I forget to accept answers.. I'll check the others, too.
Anyway, I had to relogin! That's odd.. I thought the effects were instantaneous...

Comment: Since my comment was the missing piece in the puzzle, I added it to my answer, so it might be of help for others. (And you can accept this answer ;).

Answer (score 2):

You add write privilegues with +w, not +r.

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
```

And luca has to relogin to have the group assignment changes take effect.

Comment: sorry that was a typo