# Cannot write inside folder of my group

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm trying to make a `touch file` inside the folder `/var/www` that has the following permission:

`drwxrwsr-x  3 root www-data      4096 ago 25 16:38 www`

It should belong to the group `www-data` and should have `rws` rights for user of the same group and my user `pi` also belong to that group. This is the output of `groups pi`

`pi : pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio www-data video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio`

So, where's the mistake, why I cannot write in the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was correct I just simply forget to relogin after the change of group.

Same problem here: [ubuntu 9.04 /var/www permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/250644/ubuntu-9-04-var-www-permissions)